# Code stops working correctly halfway through executing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to gather data about player stats from one spreadsheet sheet, perform a calculation on that data, and then paste that data into a cell on another sheet if the names match.

Its a bit tricky as the sheet with the stats data has less records than my other sheet, and the names are the shortened versions rather than the full names.

I have been using the Range.Find function to check if the names of the players on the stats sheet are within the names cells of the first sheet, and if so paste the formula.

My approach so far is to:
1. search the long list to see if the stats sheet name exists in the long set of names
2. if it exists, check to see if the name in the long list corresponding to the row of the current cell is the same as the name in the stats sheet, and if not, move to the next cell in the long list and check again.
3. repeat until I have the location of the cell which matches the name of the stats sheet cell, and fill in the formula in a cell on the same row as the name on the long list.

My code is (it starts to say all the names are not in the list even though they are):

```
'
' PlayerImpact Macro
'

'
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, PSrng As Range, player As Range, namerng As Range, FDaddress As Range, playercheck As Range
'Dim namek As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim a As Single, b As Single, c As Single, d As Single, tot As Single
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("P2:P542")
Set namerng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A542")
Set PSrng = Sheet6.Range("A2:S390")
k = 1
i = 2
j = 2
'For j = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
Do While j < rng.Rows.Count
    Debug.Print " "
    Debug.Print "i: " & " " & i
    Debug.Print "j: " & " " & j
    Debug.Print "k: " & " " & k
    Debug.Print "Filtered Data Player:" & " " & namerng(k)
    Debug.Print "Stats Player:" & " " & PSrng.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Set cell = rng(j)
    Set player = namerng.Find(PSrng.Cells(i, 3).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
    If Not player Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "namerange loop: " & " " & player.Value
            Debug.Print "namerange k in loop: " & " " & namerng(k)
            Debug.Print "Stats Player in loop:" & " " & PSrng.Cells(i, 3).Value
            Set playercheck = namerng(k).Find(PSrng.Cells(i, 3).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not playercheck Is Nothing Then
                j = k
                'cell.Formula = "=('Player Stats Value'!G" & (i + 1) & "-'Player Stats Value'!$G$2)/'Player Stats Value'!$G$2+('Player Stats Value'!I" & (i + 1) & "-'Player Stats Value'!$I$2)/'Player Stats Value'!$I$2+('Player Stats Value'!J" & (i + 1) & "-'Player Stats Value'!$J$2)/(2*'Player Stats Value'!$J$2)+('Player Stats Value'!K" & (i + 1) & "-'Player Stats Value'!$K$2)/(2*'Player Stats Value'!$K$2)+('Player Stats Value'!Q" & (i + 1) & "-'Player Stats Value'!$Q$2)"
                i = i + 1
                k = k + 1
                j = j + 1
                Debug.Print "In List, Player Check Match: " & " " & player.Value
                Debug.Print "Playercheck Value: " & " " & playercheck.Value
            Else
                Debug.Print "In List, No match Player Check:" & " " & player.Value
                k = k + 1
                If k > namerng.Rows.Count Then
                    k = 1
                End If
            End If
    Else
      Debug.Print "Not in List: " & " " & PSrng.Cells(i, 3).Value
      i = i + 1
      'cell.Value = 0
      j = j + 1
      'k = k + 1
    End If
Loop
```

[the two spreadsheets can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O181F.jpg)

A sample of the output when it starts to go wrong:

```
i:  13
j:  14
k:  14
Filtered Data Player: Ademola Lookman
Stats Player: Adrián
namerange loop:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
namerange k in loop:  Ademola Lookman
Stats Player in loop: Adrián
In List, No match Player Check: Adrián San Miguel del Castillo

i:  13
j:  14
k:  15
Filtered Data Player: Adrian Mariappa
Stats Player: Adrián
namerange loop:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
namerange k in loop:  Adrian Mariappa
Stats Player in loop: Adrián
In List, No match Player Check: Adrián San Miguel del Castillo

i:  13
j:  14
k:  16
Filtered Data Player: Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
Stats Player: Adrián
namerange loop:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
namerange k in loop:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
Stats Player in loop: Adrián
In List, Player Check Match:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo
Playercheck Value:  Adrián San Miguel del Castillo

i:  14
j:  17
k:  17
Filtered Data Player: Ahmed El Mohamady
Stats Player: Adrian Mariappa
Not in List:  Adrian Mariappa

i:  15
j:  18
k:  17
Filtered Data Player: Ahmed El Mohamady
Stats Player: Ahmed Elmohamady
Not in List:  Ahmed Elmohamady

i:  16
j:  19
k:  17
Filtered Data Player: Ahmed El Mohamady
Stats Player: Ainsley Maitland-Niles
Not in List:  Ainsley Maitland-Niles

i:  17
j:  20
k:  17
Filtered Data Player: Ahmed El Mohamady
Stats Player: Alex Iwobi
Not in List:  Alex Iwobi
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly is going wrong? What is the desired output compared to the actual output?

Comment: Sure, sorry if it wasnt clear.

The problem is that if you take player "Adrian Mariappa" for example, you can see at A16 of the second image he is in the long list, however my code does not recognise him as being there, even though the exact same code works for the players before him.

Comment: My comment didnt seem to work so ill post it here:

Sure, sorry if it wasnt clear.

The problem is that if you take player "Adrian Mariappa" for example, you can see at A16 of the second image he is in the long list, however my code does not recognise him as being there, even though the exact same code works for the players before him.

For example with player "Adrian" from the stats sheet, originally it is comparing him to "Ademola Lookman" from the long list, then the code increases "k" and it compares him to "Adrián San Miguel del Castillo", which is correct and executes properly.

Comment: Wouldn't you rather store data in a  dictionary? You can just check if a value exists in such an object. Your problem is probably with the whole `k` thing.

Comment: Can you please explain how I would use a dictionary in this instance? My apologies, this is the first time ive ever used VBA!

Comment: This code seems overly complicated for what I think you're trying to achieve. Could you pinpoint exactly what the desired result of this procedure is? Specifically: What information do you need and in what format? So far you're only printing stuff to the immediate window, not actually changing the workbook.

Comment: Sorry yes, I was checking the results, the actual workbook changing values have been commented out. Basically if you remove all the Debug.Prints and uncomment everything that is commented (apart from the k=k+1 at the end), that is what my final result should be. I am trying to add a formula to sheet 1 column P if a name in sheet 2 corresponds to a name (col. A) in sheet 1 in the same row as the cell in the P column. If so, add the formula, if not either skip or add make the cell value 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand about your problem, this code should do everything you're looking for:

```
Sub PlayerImpact()

Dim rng As Range, namerng As Range, PSrng As Range
Dim lngCol As Long

Set rng = Sheet1.Range("P2:P542")
Set namerng = Sheet1.Range("A2:A542")
Set PSrng = Sheet6.Range("C3:C390")

For j = 1 To namerng.Rows.Count

    If Not PSrng.Find(namerng(j).Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart) Is Nothing Then
        lngRow = PSrng.Find(namerng(j).Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlPart).Row

        rng(j).Formula = "=('Player Stats Value'!G" & lngRow & "-'Player Stats Value'!$G$2)/" & _
        "'Player Stats Value'!$G$2+('Player Stats Value'!I" & lngRow & "-'Player Stats Value'!$I$2) /" & _
        "'Player Stats Value'!$I$2+('Player Stats Value'!J" & lngRow & "-'Player Stats Value'!$J$2)/" & _
        "(2*'Player Stats Value'!$J$2)+('Player Stats Value'!K" & lngRow & "-'Player Stats Value'!$K$2)/" & _
        "(2*'Player Stats Value'!$K$2)+('Player Stats Value'!Q" & lngRow & "-'Player Stats Value'!$Q$2)"
    Else
        rng(j).Value2 = 0 'alternative: rng(j).Value2 = ""
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! What is the difference between value and value2?

Comment: [This](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) sums it up nicely. Basically, `Value2` completely "ignores" the cell formatting and is therefore faster and less prone to errors. There are some cases where `Value` is to be prefered, for example if you need to keep the formatting of a date.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection I realised that it does not quite solve the problem as intended. This solution takes the name from Sheet1 and looks for it in Sheet6. Unfortunately the names in Sheet6 are often truncated versions of the names in Sheet 1, and thus the reason why I needed to introduce the complexity in searching the names in Sheet6 in Sheet1. If you have any further ideas on how this might be implemented I would be grateful!

Comment: As far as I can see there is no reliable check for truncated names in the original code you posted, or am I missing something? A solution for this depends on if there is any logic to how the names are modified. Is there a consistent logic to how the names in Sheet6 differ from those in Sheet1?

Comment: Yes, the names in Sheet 6 are always smaller versions of the names (ie do not include middle names etc). The "i", "j" and "k" parameters in my code represent the row position of column C in Sheet 6, and cols. P and A in sheet1 respectively. "k" cycles through the list of names in Sheet1 and checks them against "i" to see if they are a match. If they are, it sets the value of "j" to wherever "k" was located and fills in the formula. Let me know if you need any further explanation happy to help.

Comment: Right, if there's missing middle names you will need a different compared to names that are simply shortened from left or right. Shortened names will be a subset of the full name, but if there's middle names missing you might need to modify the shortened names to contain a placeholder, for example: To match "John Doe" to "John Michael Doe" you would either need to separate the names or create a string like "John*Doe". To make this reliable you will need to be aware of all possible name modifications.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had success with the Range.Find in the regard- It seemed to be able to pick them up but then also seemed to stop working half way through. Im not sure if its an indexing issue or a limitation of Range.Find

Comment: That's what I mean by having a subset of characters. If you're looking for "Michael" in "John Michael Doe" (with `Lookat:=xlPart`) it will find that string. But if you're looking for "John Doe" in "John Michael Doe" it will not be found, since the complete first string is not part of the second string. "John Michael" and "Michael Doe" would be found, since they are simply a subset of the complete string. I assume that's why it sometimes works for you and sometimes doesn't.

Comment: Right! Thank you very much, I think that is the root of the issue. If I put wildcards at the beginning middle and end does that mean that the find function will only match if there is text exactly at the start middle and end, or can wildcards be blank too?

Comment: Depends on the wildcard. `?` replaces a single character. `*` can replace multiple characters, but it doesn't have to. So "John*Doe" would match "John Michael Doe" as well as "JohnDoe". "John?Doe" would match "John Doe", but not "JohnDoe". More is explained [here](https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/).